# PHP SUM total in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am new in PHP but I want to Sum my amount and display it on the page currently I am doing like this but it is not showing.

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel panel-bordered panel-black">
                <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo translate('Total Amount ');?></h3>
                 </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1>
<?php 
 echo $this->db->select('SUM(amount) as Total');
 $getData =  $this->db->get_where('tablename',array('amount = '!=0))->first_row();
 echo $getData->Total; 
 ?>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$data = $this->db->get_where('tablename',array('amount = '=>1))->sum(amount)->result();
foreach($data as $row): 
echo $row['amount'];  //if array output
echo $row->amount; //object output
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Dr. Strange thank you fr the reply i have tried your suggested solution it seems to not working.

Comment: there is no error the page is coming as blank. but if i am just countig the rows it is working fine

Comment: @FulufheloPraiseMunyai have to tired print_r(data) ?;

Comment: try this `echo $row->amount;` @FulufheloPraiseMunyai

Comment: @Dr.Strange it is still coming black, i have attached a picture that is returning the total number of rows and that is working correctly.

Comment: you have try this `print_r($data) ?;` @FulufheloPraiseMunyai

Comment: @Dr.Strange yes i have tried it still having a blank page

Comment: so you can print the query and send me if possible..!@FulufheloPraiseMunyai

Comment: @Dr.Strange,deadman, I have managed to fix it i have updated my code on the question with a working code. Thanks a lot much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel panel-bordered panel-black">
                <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo translate('Total Amount ');?></h3>
                 </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1>
<?php 
 echo $this->db->select('SUM(amount) as Total');
 $getData =  $this->db->get_where('tablename',array('amount = '!=0))->first_row();
 echo $getData->Total; 
 ?>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```